# How do I use OpenID and implement it in my Laravel app?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, openid

I'm learning Laravel slowly and am trying to figure out how to implement OpenID for my app so I can allow users to sign in either using Google/Facebook/Twitter or the site's own registration system.

I (personally) find the documentation for OpenID is frustratingly lacking (even the official "getting started" just points to a bunch of plugins and leaves it at that). I am really struggling to figure it out. This is my first time even trying to tango with OpenID and I want to do this properly.

If anyone could either provide me with some detailed guide or help me along with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmycoder/lightopenid - This is a fork of an OpenId library that I use. It allows you to implement OpenID by only knowing the endpoint URL of the service (Google Federated Login is included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look elsewhere! I suggest you to delve into the following series by [Philip Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373221/philipbrown):

- [Adding Social Authentication to a Laravel 4 application Part 1](http://culttt.com/2014/05/26/adding-social-authentication-laravel-4-application-part-1/).
- [Adding Social Authentication to a Laravel 4 application Part 2](http://culttt.com/2014/06/02/adding-social-authentication-laravel-4-application-part-2/).
- [Adding Social Authentication to a Laravel 4 application Part 3](http://culttt.com/2014/06/09/adding-social-authentication-laravel-4-application-part-3/).

Comment: Er... this series doesn't cover OpenID.